# can i able to send broadcast to default sms application in android?

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public class MMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        String incomingNumber = null;
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED"))
         {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                try
                {
                    if (bundle != null)
                    {
                        String type = intent.getType();
                        if(type.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.wap.mms-message"))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = bundle.getByteArray("data");
                            incomingNumber = new String(buffer);
                            int indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("/TYPE");
                            if(indx>0 && (indx-15)>0)
                            {
                                int newIndx = indx - 15;
                                incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(newIndx, indx);
                                indx = incomingNumber.indexOf("+");
                                if(indx>0)
                                {
                                    incomingNumber = incomingNumber.substring(indx);
                                    System.out.println("Mobile Number: " + incomingNumber);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I have bundle data with me when sms arrives to my device .Then can i able to send broadcast with this bundle data to default sms application

Comment: By default broadcast will send to all application registered for this. until the application which received prior doesn't destroy it

Comment: what do you want to do. you want to receive a broadcast or you want to send one ?

Comment: My requirement is in Android 4.4(later) there is one option called we can able to make our sms application as default sms application that is sms provider.At that time prevous default application(sms provider) unable to recieve the action.So our application is responsible to send that data to smsprovider because our sms application may crash in future .see this link for better understanding :http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: In android blogspot he mentioned like, Only default SMS app is able to write the data to provider remaining only read from data from provider k.But I want to know how to write data from Default SMS app to Sms provider.Is there any example code suggest me .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you getting a sms broadcast event, you don't need to send from your side. As the same broadcast will be received by all applications watching for that intent.

Now unless, you want to change something. then you need to cancel the broadcast and make your own broadcast and fire it. and yes you can do that. make sure, your receiver priority is high enough to receive event before other apps do.

Hope this is what you asking.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: My requirement is in Android 4.4(later) there is one option called we can able to make our sms application as default sms application that is sms provider.At that time prevous default application(sms provider) unable to recieve the action.So our application is responsible to send that data to smsprovider because our sms application may crash in future .see this link for better understanding  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: are you making your application as default sms application?

Comment: ya exactly ,i want to make my sms application as default sms application.At that time the previous default application(sms provider) is unable to recieve action so our application is responsible to send broadcast with bundle data .That is what i want .Thank you

Comment: Hi Farhan,Suggest me how can i send data from default sms application to sms provider through broadcast or anyway.Thank you

Comment: In android blogspot he mentioned like, Only default SMS app is able to write the data to provider remaining only read from data from provider k.But I want to know how to write data from Default SMS app to Sms provider.Is there any example code suggest me .Thank you

Comment: K Farhan,this is the link for that Blog defaultSMS feature in Android 4.4 kitkat http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html